# Sum of Max after a series of grouping in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have 48 columns to display data for each 1/2 hour and the corresponding date. It was all okay and suddenly my client wants to change this such that TO DISPLAY ONLY Maximum value off these 48 columns for each day. I tired Max conversion, pivot, etc etc but in vain.

Currently it's like

```
  Date           [12:00am] [12:30am] ....   [11:30pm]        
      01/01/2012         5        6               9      
      01/02/2012         15       4               8       
      01/03/2012         1        19              0
```

but I have to get it like (only 2 columns)

```
Date          Max(out of these 48 cols)
01/01/2012         9
01/02/2012         15
01/03/2012         19
```

Appreciate any help.

Note: I do not have any direct columns to compute max or sum.

Code snippet:

```
    DECLARE     @prmOffSet int,@prmStartDate datetime, @prmEndDate datetime
    SET @prmStartDate = '01/01/2012';
    SET @prmEndDate = '01/10/2012';
    SET @prmOffSet = '-8';
    SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST

(StartDate AS DateTime), 101) AS StartDate, 
        SUM(TwelveAM) AS [12:00am],
        SUM(TwelveThirtyAM) AS [12:30am], 
        SUM(OneAM) AS [1:00am], 
        SUM(OneThirtyAM) AS [1:30am],
        SUM(TwoAM) AS [2:00am], 
        SUM(TwoThirtyAM) AS [2:30am],
        SUM(ThreeAM) AS [3:00am],
        SUM(ThreeThirtyAM) AS [3:30am], 
        SUM(FourAM) AS [4:00am], 
        SUM(FourThirtyAM) AS [4:30am],
        SUM(FiveAM) AS [5:00am],
        SUM(FiveThirtyAM) AS [5:30am], 
        SUM(SixAM) AS [6:00am], 
        SUM(SixThirtyAM) AS [6:30am],
        SUM(SevenAM) AS [7:00am],
        SUM(SevenThirtyAM) AS [7:30am], 
        SUM(EightAM) AS [8:00am],
        SUM(EightThirtyAM) AS [8:30am],  
        SUM(NineAM) AS [9:00am],
        SUM(NineThirtyAM) AS [9:30am], 
        SUM(TenAM) AS [10:00am],
        SUM(TenThirtyAM) AS [10:30am], 
        SUM(ElevenAM) AS [11:00am], 
        SUM(ElevenThirtyAM) AS [11:30am],
        SUM(TwelvePM) AS [12:00pm],
        SUM(TwelveThirtyPM) AS [12:30pm], 
        SUM(OnePM) AS [1:00pm], 
        SUM(OneThirtyPM) AS [1:30pm],
        SUM(TwoPM) AS [2:00pm], 
        SUM(TwoThirtyPM) AS [2:30pm],
        SUM(ThreePM) AS [3:00pm], 
        SUM(ThreeThirtyPM) AS [3:30pm],
        SUM(FourPM) AS [4:00pm], 
        SUM(FourThirtyPM) AS [4:30pm],
        SUM(FivePM) AS [5:00pm],
        SUM(FiveThirtyPM) AS [5:30pm], 
        SUM(SixPM) AS [6:00pm], 
        SUM(SixThirtyPM) AS [6:30pm],
        SUM(SevenPM) AS [7:00pm], 
        SUM(SevenThirtyPM) AS [7:30pm],
        SUM(EightPM) AS [8:00pm], 
        SUM(EightThirtyPM) AS [8:30pm],
        SUM(NinePM) AS [9:00pm], 
        SUM(NineThirtyPM) AS [9:30pm],
        SUM(TenPM) AS [10:00pm],
        SUM(TenThirtyPM) AS [10:30pm], 
        SUM(ElevenPM) AS [11:00pm],
        SUM(ElevenThirtyPM) AS [11:30pm]
FROM (
        SELECT DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 0 AND EndHours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwelveAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 0.5 AND EndHours >= 0.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwelveThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 1 AND EndHours >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OneAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 1.5 AND EndHours >= 1.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OneThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 2 AND EndHours >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 2.5 AND EndHours >= 2.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 3 AND EndHours >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThreeAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 3.5 AND EndHours >= 3.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThreeThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 4 AND EndHours >= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FourAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 4.5 AND EndHours >= 4.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FourThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 5 AND EndHours >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FiveAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 5.5 AND EndHours >= 5.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FiveThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 6 AND EndHours >= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SixAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 6.5 AND EndHours >= 6.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SixThirtyAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 7 AND EndHours >= 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SevenAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 7.5 AND EndHours >= 7.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SevenThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 8 AND EndHours >= 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EightAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 8.5 AND EndHours >= 8.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EightThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 9 AND EndHours >= 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NineAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 9.5 AND EndHours >= 9.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NineThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 10.0 AND EndHours >= 10.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TenAM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 10.5 AND EndHours >= 10.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TenThirtyAM,         
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 11 AND EndHours >= 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ElevenAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 11.5 AND EndHours >= 11.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ElevenThirtyAM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 12 AND EndHours >= 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwelvePM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 12.5 AND EndHours >= 12.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwelveThirtyPM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 13 AND EndHours >= 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OnePM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 13.5 AND EndHours >= 13.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OneThirtyPM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 14 AND EndHours >= 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoPM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 14.5 AND EndHours >= 14.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoThirtyPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 15 AND EndHours >= 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThreePM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 15.5 AND EndHours >= 15.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThreeThirtyPM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 16 AND EndHours >= 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FourPM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 16.5 AND EndHours >= 16.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FourThirtyPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 17 AND EndHours >= 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FivePM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 17.5 AND EndHours >= 17.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FiveThirtyPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 18 AND EndHours >= 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SixPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 18.5 AND EndHours >= 18.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SixThirtyPM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 19 AND EndHours >= 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SevenPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 19.5 AND EndHours >= 19.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SevenThirtyPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 20 AND EndHours >= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EightPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 20.5 AND EndHours >= 20.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EightThirtyPM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 21 AND EndHours >= 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NinePM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 21.5 AND EndHours >= 21.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NineThirtyPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 22 AND EndHours >= 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TenPM, 
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 22.5 AND EndHours >= 22.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TenThirtyPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 23 AND EndHours >= 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ElevenPM,
            CASE WHEN StartHours <= 23.5 AND EndHours >= 23.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ElevenThirtyPM
        FROM (
                SELECT DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours
                FROM (
                    SELECT DisplayName, 
                        CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS StartDate, 
                        DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) as Start,
                        CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS EndDate, 
                        DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)) as [End],
                        DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart)) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(mi, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart))<30 THEN 0.0 ELSE 0.5 END AS StartHours, 
                        DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity))) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(mi, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)))<30 THEN 0.0 ELSE 0.5 END AS EndHours
                    FROM tbSessionLog SL LEFT OUTER JOIN tbSessions S ON SL.SessionID=S.SessionID
                    WHERE (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(@prmStartDate AS DATETIME)) AND 
                          (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) <= CAST(@prmEndDate AS DATETIME))) AS Sess
                GROUP BY DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours) AS DtlSess) AS HourCount
GROUP BY StartDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bluefeet, thanks for your prompt responses. I have solved it using the unpivot. For the record, who may have similar issue can refer the soln below.

```
 SELECT StartDate,Max(col) As MaxValue
FROM
(
    SELECT StartDate, col
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(StartDate AS DateTime), 101) AS StartDate, 
                SUM(TwelveAM) AS [12:00am],
                SUM(TwelveThirtyAM) AS [12:30am], 
                SUM(OneAM) AS [1:00am], 
                SUM(OneThirtyAM) AS [1:30am],
                SUM(TwoAM) AS [2:00am], 
                SUM(TwoThirtyAM) AS [2:30am],
                SUM(ThreeAM) AS [3:00am],
                SUM(ThreeThirtyAM) AS [3:30am], 
                SUM(FourAM) AS [4:00am], 
                SUM(FourThirtyAM) AS [4:30am],
                SUM(FiveAM) AS [5:00am],
                SUM(FiveThirtyAM) AS [5:30am], 
                SUM(SixAM) AS [6:00am], 
                SUM(SixThirtyAM) AS [6:30am],
                SUM(SevenAM) AS [7:00am],
                SUM(SevenThirtyAM) AS [7:30am], 
                SUM(EightAM) AS [8:00am],
                SUM(EightThirtyAM) AS [8:30am],  
                SUM(NineAM) AS [9:00am],
                SUM(NineThirtyAM) AS [9:30am], 
                SUM(TenAM) AS [10:00am],
                SUM(TenThirtyAM) AS [10:30am], 
                SUM(ElevenAM) AS [11:00am], 
                SUM(ElevenThirtyAM) AS [11:30am],
                SUM(TwelvePM) AS [12:00pm],
                SUM(TwelveThirtyPM) AS [12:30pm], 
                SUM(OnePM) AS [1:00pm], 
                SUM(OneThirtyPM) AS [1:30pm],
                SUM(TwoPM) AS [2:00pm], 
                SUM(TwoThirtyPM) AS [2:30pm],
                SUM(ThreePM) AS [3:00pm], 
                SUM(ThreeThirtyPM) AS [3:30pm],
                SUM(FourPM) AS [4:00pm], 
                SUM(FourThirtyPM) AS [4:30pm],
                SUM(FivePM) AS [5:00pm],
                SUM(FiveThirtyPM) AS [5:30pm], 
                SUM(SixPM) AS [6:00pm], 
                SUM(SixThirtyPM) AS [6:30pm],
                SUM(SevenPM) AS [7:00pm], 
                SUM(SevenThirtyPM) AS [7:30pm],
                SUM(EightPM) AS [8:00pm], 
                SUM(EightThirtyPM) AS [8:30pm],
                SUM(NinePM) AS [9:00pm], 
                SUM(NineThirtyPM) AS [9:30pm],
                SUM(TenPM) AS [10:00pm],
                SUM(TenThirtyPM) AS [10:30pm], 
                SUM(ElevenPM) AS [11:00pm],
                SUM(ElevenThirtyPM) AS [11:30pm]
        FROM (
                SELECT DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 0 AND EndHours >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwelveAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 0.5 AND EndHours >= 0.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwelveThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 1 AND EndHours >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OneAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 1.5 AND EndHours >= 1.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OneThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 2 AND EndHours >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 2.5 AND EndHours >= 2.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 3 AND EndHours >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThreeAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 3.5 AND EndHours >= 3.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThreeThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 4 AND EndHours >= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FourAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 4.5 AND EndHours >= 4.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FourThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 5 AND EndHours >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FiveAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 5.5 AND EndHours >= 5.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FiveThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 6 AND EndHours >= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SixAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 6.5 AND EndHours >= 6.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SixThirtyAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 7 AND EndHours >= 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SevenAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 7.5 AND EndHours >= 7.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SevenThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 8 AND EndHours >= 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EightAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 8.5 AND EndHours >= 8.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EightThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 9 AND EndHours >= 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NineAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 9.5 AND EndHours >= 9.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NineThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 10.0 AND EndHours >= 10.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TenAM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 10.5 AND EndHours >= 10.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TenThirtyAM,         
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 11 AND EndHours >= 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ElevenAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 11.5 AND EndHours >= 11.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ElevenThirtyAM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 12 AND EndHours >= 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwelvePM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 12.5 AND EndHours >= 12.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwelveThirtyPM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 13 AND EndHours >= 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OnePM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 13.5 AND EndHours >= 13.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OneThirtyPM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 14 AND EndHours >= 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoPM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 14.5 AND EndHours >= 14.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TwoThirtyPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 15 AND EndHours >= 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThreePM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 15.5 AND EndHours >= 15.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ThreeThirtyPM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 16 AND EndHours >= 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FourPM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 16.5 AND EndHours >= 16.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FourThirtyPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 17 AND EndHours >= 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FivePM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 17.5 AND EndHours >= 17.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FiveThirtyPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 18 AND EndHours >= 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SixPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 18.5 AND EndHours >= 18.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SixThirtyPM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 19 AND EndHours >= 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SevenPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 19.5 AND EndHours >= 19.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SevenThirtyPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 20 AND EndHours >= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EightPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 20.5 AND EndHours >= 20.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EightThirtyPM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 21 AND EndHours >= 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NinePM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 21.5 AND EndHours >= 21.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NineThirtyPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 22 AND EndHours >= 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TenPM, 
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 22.5 AND EndHours >= 22.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TenThirtyPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 23 AND EndHours >= 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ElevenPM,
                    CASE WHEN StartHours <= 23.5 AND EndHours >= 23.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ElevenThirtyPM
                FROM (
                        SELECT DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours
                        FROM (
                            SELECT DisplayName, 
                                CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS StartDate, 
                                DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) as Start,
                                CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS EndDate, 
                                DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)) as [End],
                                DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart)) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(mi, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart))<30 THEN 0.0 ELSE 0.5 END AS StartHours, 
                                DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity))) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(mi, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)))<30 THEN 0.0 ELSE 0.5 END AS EndHours
                            FROM tbSessionLog SL LEFT OUTER JOIN tbSessions S ON SL.SessionID=S.SessionID
                            WHERE (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(@prmStartDate AS DATETIME)) AND 
                                  (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) <= CAST(@prmEndDate AS DATETIME))) AS Sess
                        GROUP BY DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours) AS DtlSess) AS HourCount
        GROUP BY StartDate
) T1
UNPIVOT
  (col FOR ListofColumns IN ([12:00AM],[12:30AM],[1:00AM],[1:30AM],[2:00AM],[2:30AM],[3:00AM],[3:30AM],[4:00AM],[4:30AM],[5:00AM],[5:30AM],[6:00AM],[6:30AM],[7:00AM],[7:30AM],[8:00AM],[8:30AM],[9:00AM],[9:30AM],[10:00AM],[10:30AM],[11:00AM],[11:30AM],[12:00PM],[12:30PM],[1:00PM],[1:30PM],[2:00PM],[2:30PM],[3:00PM],[3:30PM],[4:00PM],[4:30PM],[5:00PM],[5:30PM],[6:00PM],[6:30PM],[7:00PM],[7:30PM],[8:00PM],[8:30PM],[9:00PM],[9:30PM],[10:00PM],[10:30PM],[11:00PM],[11:30PM]))
    AS unpivott) as T2
Group by StartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can see that you can easily get this result is to not perform the `PIVOT` and create the 48 columns.

If you create the 48 columns, then you would have to `UNPIVOT` those columns to get the `Max` total for each day.

I would suggest a slight change to your current query to something like the following. Instead of using the `CASE` statement to create new columns, use one columns with an identifier for each hour block:

```
CASE 
  WHEN StartHours <= 0 AND EndHours >= 0 THEN 'TwelveAM'  
  WHEN StartHours <= 0.5 AND EndHours >= 0.5 THEN 'TwelveThirtyAM'
  WHEN StartHours <= 1 AND EndHours >= 1 THEN 'OneAM' 
  WHEN StartHours <= 1.5 AND EndHours >= 1.5 THEN 'OneThirtyAM'
  WHEN StartHours <= 2 AND EndHours >= 2 THEN 'TwoAM' 
  WHEN StartHours <= 2.5 AND EndHours >= 2.5 THEN 'TwoThirtyAM'
END as Hours
```

Once this data is in a single column, then you can perform a count of each hour and then you can get the `Max` total for each day.

So your query will be similar to this:

```
SELECT StartDate, Max(TotalHours)
FROM
(
  SELECT StartDate, Hours, count(Hours) TotalHours
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours, 
      CASE 
        WHEN StartHours <= 0 AND EndHours >= 0 THEN 'TwelveAM'  
        WHEN StartHours <= 0.5 AND EndHours >= 0.5 THEN 'TwelveThirtyAM'
        WHEN StartHours <= 1 AND EndHours >= 1 THEN 'OneAM' 
        WHEN StartHours <= 1.5 AND EndHours >= 1.5 THEN 'OneThirtyAM'
        WHEN StartHours <= 2 AND EndHours >= 2 THEN 'TwoAM' 
        WHEN StartHours <= 2.5 AND EndHours >= 2.5 THEN 'TwoThirtyAM'
        -- add other WHEN statements here
      END as Hours
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT DisplayName, 
         CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS StartDate, 
         DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) as Start,
         CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS EndDate, 
         DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)) as [End],
         DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart)) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(mi, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart))<30 THEN 0.0 ELSE 0.5 END AS StartHours, 
         DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity))) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(mi, DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, ISNULL(SL.SessionUTCEnd,S.LastActivity)))<30 THEN 0.0 ELSE 0.5 END AS EndHours
        FROM tbSessionLog SL 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbSessions S 
          ON SL.SessionID=S.SessionID
        WHERE (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(@prmStartDate AS DATETIME)) AND 
          (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(hh, @prmOffSet, SL.SessionUTCStart) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) <= CAST(@prmEndDate AS DATETIME))
      ) AS Sess
      GROUP BY DisplayName, StartDate, EndDate, StartHours, EndHours
    ) AS DtlSess
  ) src
  GROUP BY StartDate, Hours
) t
GROUP BY StartDate
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd349/2) with a shortened version of your query.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, I am trying to modify this or will take a different approach from base. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1776609 can you create a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables and some sample data?